# How to specify child padding/spacing to a TCustomControl in Lazarus?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

In Delphi I could use `Padding` to specify how much spacing there would be between any child controls and my custom control. This is useful for example if the custom control has a caption section at the top and thus any aligned child controls would appear under the caption part, it's basically ensuring that child controls cannot be positioned or overlapping in parts of your control that you don't want them to be at.

I am trying to achieve this in Lazarus but as there is no `Padding` property I need some other alternative. The closest thing I found was `ChildSizing` but I cannot see an obvious way to implement it.

See this attached image:

[image]

The `TMemo` is child to my custom control and the way the spacing was achieved is like so:

```
constructor TMyControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Self.ControlStyle := Self.ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls];
  Self.BorderStyle  := bsSingle;
  Self.Height       := 210;  
  Self.Width        := 320;
  Self.ChildSizing.TopBottomSpacing := 10; // This line adds the spacing
end;
```

As you can see from the attached image though, there is spacing at the top and bottom of the control which I expected to happen given the property name `TopBottomSpacing`.

There does not seem to be an obvious property that I can see to deal with simply adding spacing at the top, bottom, left or right independently:

[image]

How can I specify child spacing independently in Lazarus?

I can only see `TopBottomSpacing` and `LeftRightSpacing` which have the unwanted effect of adding spacing on the opposite sides, I only want to add padding/spacing at the top.

Comment: `TLCLComponent` have `BorderSpacing` property. You can visually edit it by right-click -> Anchor Editor on the control.

Comment: Try `Self.AnchorSideTop.Control := Self.Parent;` Of course it must be called when `Parent` sets. Override `procedure SetParent(NewParent: TWinControl); virtual;` method for example.

Comment: BTW it seems that I misunderstand the your goal. Try to override `procedure AdjustClientRect(var ARect: TRect); virtual;` method. You can look at `procedure TCustomPanel.AdjustClientRect(var aRect: TRect); override;` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the area to which are child controls can be anchored, override `AdjustClientRect` method like:

```
procedure TMyControl.AdjustClientRect(var ARect: TRect);
begin
    inherited AdjustClientRect(ARect);
    ARect := Rect(
        ARect.Left, 
        ARect.Top + Canvas.TextHeight('A'), // Make place for control's header
        ARect.Right, 
        ARect.Bottom);
    // Or just:
    // ARect.Top += Canvas.TextHeight('A');
end;
```

Also keep in mind the warning from developers:

```
procedure TWinControl.AdjustClientRect(var ARect: TRect);
begin
  // Can be overriden.
  // It's called often, so don't put expensive code here, or cache the result
end;
```